# On one Mac, Xcode does not correctly attach to debug a privileged helper and I cannot set breakpoints etc. On another machine it works. Any solution?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am developing a macOS application that uses a privileged helper following [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/EvenBetterAuthorizationSample/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013768-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) very good Apple example, "Even Better Authorization Sample". Using the "Attach to process by PID or name" Xcode feature, I should be able to debug and set breakpoints both in the host app and the privileged helper. However, on my production machine this does not work and Xcode never stops on breakpoints, although it claims to be attached as root. I have System Integrity Protection disabled. I am using Xcode 12.3. On another Mac it works and it debugs the helper properly. Anybody has a suggestion ? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Just wondering - you mention on your *production* machine. You run it in release mode there? Are you using same targets on both sides? That said, how do you sync between the two machines? If you sync properly then the breakpoints would also be transferred from one machine to the other.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am transferring the entire project folder to the other machine where it works.